# Any best practice on how to represent player progress stat in a game?

Tags: gui-design, info-visualisation, statistics, progress

I'm making a musical game where user should recognize notes and get faster at note reading. I'm in the designing process and I get quite stuck on the designing of the player progress on the level representation.

Here is what I got so far:

[image: Try 1]

Using percentage is great for progress and knowing where to train, but does not represent a speed.

Other try:

[image: Try 2]

Using speed is great but on the other side, does not give much information to the player if he's great or not (is 10 BPM great or not?)

So I'm looking for best practice in design UI assets or creative ideas to show player progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for a particular 'exercise' or 'task' you want to represent two bits of information.

- Progress of the exercise (i.e. how much of it they have completed)
- Competency of the exercise (i.e. how well they are doing)

Depending on how this is computed, you can either combine them together or show them as separate stats.

For example, if the exercise can be broken into parts (which is where the progress or % complete comes from I guess), then you can show a summary as a percentage. Otherwise you would just show it as being complete or incomplete.

Also, if each part of the exercise as a sub-score, then you can show the average speed (weighted or simple average) for each section of the exercise.

I think what is missing from the information provided is just what a good speed would be. As you say, 10 BPM doesn't mean anything. You can compare it to the user's previous speed or use some defined benchmark if you want to make meaningful comparisons.